# Haskell sqlite-simple fold IO

Tags: sqlite, haskell, fold, sqlite-simple

I am trying to use the fold_ function from Haskell's sqlite-simple package, but how do I call it? I have it in a 'do block' in main, but none of my attempts have been able to compile. I am able to get the query_ function to work, but now I need to retrive the values one at a time. As an example, I am trying to sum a list of integers from the database.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- open "C:\\project.DB"
    theSum <- fold_ conn "SELECT rserial from conitr1" 0 (\tot val -> val + tot )
    close conn
```

I understand that it's doing an IO operation, and that I probably need to specify the type somewhere, but nothing I try seems to work. The api documentation is here http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/sqlite-simple/0.4.2.0/doc/html/Database-SQLite-Simple.html#v:fold

Comment: Try giving `val` and `tot` type signatures in your lambda, like this: `(\tot val -> (val :: Int) + (tot :: Int))`.

Comment: I finally got it! It turns out MySQL-simple has a very similar API. Here is what the anonymous function should be `(\tot (Only val) -> return $ (val::Int) + tot )`

Answer (score 1):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- open "C:\\project.DB"
    theSum <- fold_ conn "SELECT rserial from conitr1" 0 (\tot (Only val) -> return $ (val::Int) + tot )
    close conn
```

I found an example here https://github.com/nurpax/db-bench/blob/master/haskell/Sqlite.hs#L24 and it works the same! Reading a type signature is the best place to start, but sometimes its not enough.